ASP.NET Core MVC : model binding issues - view is passing null values to the action method of the controller
The form field property of my view is sending null values to the controller.
I have this view model:
public class CreateProductViewModel
{
    public List<TblProduct> getCreatedProduct { get; set; }
    public Create_Product objcreateproduct { get; set; }
}

Here are the properties of the Create_Product class:
public class Create_Product
{     
    public string ? Name { get; set; }
    public string? Strength { get; set; }
    public string? PackSize { get; set; }
    public string? Description { get; set; }
}

And here are the properties of the TblProduct class:
public partial class TblProduct
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public string? Strenght { get; set; }
    public string? PackSize { get; set; }
    public string? Description { get; set; }
    public string? Status { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Timestamp { get; set; }
}

Here is the view with its model:
@model WangarauFoods.Models.CreateProductViewModel

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <form method="post" asp-action="CreateProduct" asp-controller="Sales">
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="" class="form-label">Products Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="**objcreateproduct.Name**">
            </div>

            <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="" class="form-label">Product Strength</label>
             <input type="password" class="form-control" asp-for=**"objcreateproduct.Strength"**>
            </div>

            <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="" class="form-label">Pack Size</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="**objcreateproduct.PackSize**">
            </div>


            <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="" class="form-label">Description</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="**objcreateproduct.Description**">
            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">Strength</th>
                    <th scope="col">PackSize</th>
                    <th scope="col">Description</th>
                    <th scope="col">Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                @foreach (var product in Model.getCreatedProduct)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@product.Name</td>
                        <td>@product.Strenght</td>
                        <td>@product.PackSize</td>
                        <td>@product.Description</td>
                        <td><a href="/Home/EditSalesItem/@product.Id"> View</a> </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

Here is the controller:
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult CreateProduct(Create_Product createProd)
{
    //wDbCOntext.TblProducts.Where(x => x.Id == Int64.Parse(ID)).ToList();

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var product = new TblProduct
            {
                Name = createProd.Name,
                Strenght = createProd.Strength,
                PackSize = createProd.PackSize,
                Description = createProd.Description,
                Status = "1",
                Timestamp = null
            };

        wDbCOntext.TblProducts.Add(product);
        wDbCOntext.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("CreateProduct");
    }
    else
    {
        // Log ModelState errors for debugging
        foreach (var modelStateEntry in ModelState.Values)
        {
            foreach (var error in modelStateEntry.Errors)
            {
                // Log or debug the error message
                Console.WriteLine(error.ErrorMessage);
            }
        }

         // Return the view with validation errors
         return View();
    }

    return View();
}

Everything looks good to me. I notice when I use the model class Create_Product directly, the views sends value, but when I try to access it through the view model, null values are sent to the controller.
I have checked meticulously to ensure all fields in the view are exactly what I have in the Create_Product class.
Can anyone assist please?

Since the model bound in your view is CreateProductViewModel, the model type in the controller should also be consistent:
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult CreateProduct(CreateProductViewModel createProd)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var product = new TblProduct
        {
            Name = createProd.objcreateproduct.Name,
            Strenght = createProd.objcreateproduct.Strength,
            PackSize = createProd.objcreateproduct.PackSize,
            Description = createProd.objcreateproduct.Description,
            Status = "1",
            Timestamp = null
        };
    }

// some searches


        return View();
}

View:
@model CreateProductViewModel

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <form method="post" asp-action="CreateProduct" asp-controller="Home">
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="" class="form-label">Products Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="objcreateproduct.Name">
            </div>

            <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="" class="form-label">Product Strength</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" asp-for="objcreateproduct.Strength">
            </div>

            <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="" class="form-label">Pack Size</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="objcreateproduct.PackSize">
            </div>


            <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="" class="form-label">Description</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="objcreateproduct.Description">
            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">Strength</th>
                    <th scope="col">PackSize</th>
                    <th scope="col">Description</th>
                    <th scope="col">Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                @foreach (var product in Model.getCreatedProduct)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@product.Name</td>
                        <td>@product.Strenght</td>
                        <td>@product.PackSize</td>
                        <td>@product.Description</td>
                        <td><a href=/Home/EditSalesItem/@product.Id> View</a> </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

You can check whether the request data is successfully sent in the developer tools:


After clicking the submit button and submitting, You can see that the data was successfully received:

